# Remover hyperlink de uma imagem com jQuery

Tags: jquery

É possível remover com jQuery o hyperlink desta imagem? Pode ser simples, procurei inclusive em inglês mas não encontrei o código ou instrução adequada.

```
<a href="sushione2p.jpg">
    <img class="alignright wp-image-69" src="sushione2p-250x166.jpg">
</a>
```

O resultado esperado é:

```
<img class="alignright wp-image-69" src="sushione2p-250x166.jpg">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim, é possível.

O jQuery possui uma função chamada [`unwrap`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/), que remove o pai do elemento deixando o elemento (filho) no lugar dele.

No caso específico ficaria:

```
$('img').unwrap();
```

É claro que pode personalizar devido ao seletor.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S6u5X/) do código.

Comment: Obrigado pela rápida ajuda. Estou aprendendo e gostando muito do biblioteca.

Comment: Essa é a resposta certa

Comment: Centenas de anos mexendo com jQuery e ainda não conhecia essa função.

Comment: @Kazzkiq, jQuery é realmente muito grande, cada dia a  gente descobre uma coisa diferente hehe.